# accessing Local Storage or SQLite from cordova plugin java files

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have a plugin for my ionic project [auth-dialog](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-plugin-auth-dialog) and it creates dialog box and handle the authentication , and for android platform there is a code like this

```
 ` public AuthenticationDialog(Context context, String host, String realm) {
    mContext = context;
    mHost = host;
    mRealm = realm;
    createDialog();

}

public String getUsername() {
    return "AMASYS\\DevUser";
}

public String getPassword() {
    return "******";
}`
```

now I want to change those two methods (getUsername , getPassword)
in order to get data (username,password) from Local storage or SQLite so is there any library or method that I can use in this java class to make connection to SQLite or read from Local storage ?

I also added username and password to local storage/ SQLite using cordova plugin witch was written in js before.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First: I know this answer doesn't really answer to getting stuff from localstorage or SQLite.

But there exists [a cordova plugin](https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage), `NativeStorage` which stores data natively.
This data can be accessed in Java as shown in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159754/how-get-data-from-cordova-plugin-nativestorage-in-android-java).